# If $X$ is a topological space homeomorphic to $D^n$ then every continuous $f:X\to X$ has a fixed point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is Rotman "Intro to Algebraic Topology" Exercise 0.4:

> If $X$ is a topological space homeomorphic to $D^n$, then every continuous $f:X\to X$ has a fixed point.

How can this be shown?

Comment: Did Rotman prove that it is true for $X = D^n$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, it is given as Theorem 0.3 of his book, attributed to Brouwer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous function. Since $X \cong D^n$, we have a homeomorphism (i.e., a continuous bijection with continuous inverse) $h:X \to D^n$. Consider the diagram
$$
D^n \xrightarrow{h^{-1}} X \xrightarrow{f} X \xrightarrow h D^n,
$$
and observe that the composition $g := h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is continuous as the composition of continuous functions. Therefore by Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem, there exists $x\in D^n$ such that $g(x)=x$. As a consequence, $f(h^{-1}(x))= h^{-1}(x)$, so $f$ also has a fixed point.

Comment: You need to say homeomorphism where you have continuous bijection.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fixed now, cheers